# Method changes both instances even if applied to only one of them

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, numpy, methods

I'm struggling to understand why my simple code behaves like this. I create 2 instances a and b that takes in an array as argument. Then I define a method to change one of the instances array, but then both get changed. Any idea why this happen and how can I avoid the method changing the other instance?

```
import numpy as np
class Test:
  def __init__(self, arg):
    self.arg=arg


  def change(self,i,j,new):
    self.arg[i][j]=new




array=np.array([[11,12,13]])
a=Test(array)
b=Test(array)
#prints the same as expected
print(a.arg)
print(b.arg)
print()
a.change(0,0,3)
#still prints the same, even though I did 
#not change b.arg
print(a.arg)
print(b.arg)
```

Comment: You passed *the same array* to both constructors... why did you not expect it to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you assigned the same object as the instance members. You can use `np.array(x, copy=True)` or `x.copy()` to generate a new array object:

```
array = np.array([[11,12,13]])
a = Test(array.copy())
b = Test(np.array(array, copy=True))
```

Alternatively, if your `arg` is always a `np.array`, you could do it in the `__init__` method (as noted by [roganjosh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4799172/roganjosh) in the comments):

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = np.array(arg, copy=True)
    ...
```

Comment: I think an easier solution would be to create the copy in `init`. So, `self.arg=arg.copy()`

Comment: @roganjosh I agree in general, but the class the OP showed is general enough that `arg` might not always be a `np.array`.

Comment: That's a fair point. I guess the middle ground would be `a=Test(array.copy())` to reduce the syntax.

Comment: That solved the problem. Actually it is supposed to be an np.array so doing it in init method is the best for the codes purpose, thanks !